# Action Listener for JButton, local variables

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to create multiple buttons that have the same function without actually creating multiple buttons, so I used a loop to create as many buttons as I want, and was trying to add a ActionListener in its own class. However I cannot get the buttons to do anything, because the ActionListener does not recognize "button" as a variable. Is there a way to implement the ActionListner WITHOUT adding the ActionListener in the same class as addButton?

```
public void addButton
{
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(+)
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonAction())
    }
}

public class ButtonAction implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        File file = new File("squad");
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(file);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG Images", "jpg");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("squad/" + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the listener to modify the button, then it needs to have a reference to the button. There are two possibilities:

First one: you pass it to the listener constructor, which then stores it in a field:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonAction(button))
}
```

Second one: since the listener must in fact modify the button that triggered the event, you can get the button from the event:

```
JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("squad/" + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName()));
```